# Its a good practice push target folder in the repository?

Tags: git, maven, sonarqube, jacoco

I am covering my code, and for this I have to use JaCoCo, but for it to work in Sonar I have to upload the target folder, since Sonar does not run my tests, so I would like to know if it is a good practice to upload the folder target that Maven generates. A partner told me that it was not a good practice.

Comment: No it is not good practice to push the target folder.

Comment: So how can I upload the files generated by jacoco, since it generates them in the target folder @ruohola

Comment: Don't have things in git you can regenerate from other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may have to remove the target/ folder from your .gitignore file. Your .gitignore file has a list of all the files and directories that gi should ignore when pushing to your repository.